# How to configure Notify extension in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, email, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

I have seen many posts which are not helping. I can see that hook is getting called but not able to see any output in the output log when I set `Test="True"`

I followed many posts mentioning to make changes in `hgrc` file, but I'm wondering how changing my local `hgrc` file affects all other users. I suppose changes to be made in the repository.

Please guide me how to troubleshoot where the issue is.

Comment: Maybe add to your question the (pertinent) contents of your hgrc file